# How formal is “Bless [him/her]”?

Tags: expressions, british-english, formality

I am living in the UK, and I have recently started noticing quite a lot of people saying *“bless [him/her]”*, in contexts similar to:

> — He has been doing poorly.
> — Oh, bless him!

> — She is so cute, bless her!

British dictionaries ([Ox](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bless_1#bless_idmg_3) [brigde](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bless)) mention that this is *informal* language.

**How informal is this expression, actually?**

Out of curiosity: is it [U or non-U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English)? Would it be appropriate to say that at work (say, in an office/executive type of job), or is it too slang-ish? What does it show through (in terms of background) when one says it? Does it depend on the actual usage (e.g., OLD gives *“Sarah, bless her, had made a cup of tea.”* as another example)?

Comment: Which part of the UK?

Comment: Bless is used in expressions such as `God bless' or 'Bless you' to express affection, thanks, or good wishes. (INFORMAL, SPOKEN) Collins Dictionary. I think it's non-U, as it is short for '(May) God bless you'. U would rather say '(May) God bless you'.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica England (east of)

Comment: It's not slang, just a rather cosy, 'old-fashioned' way of referring to someone, perhaps slightly patronising. "Wasn't it kind of dear Sarah to think of making us tea at this moment?"

Comment: People often just say 'bless' these days, which is much less objectionable than the awful American 'awwwwww'.

Comment: Do I mean awwwwwwwwwwwful?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Bless your heart!

Comment: It would sound out of place (patronising or, worse, sarcastic) in a formal situation. It needs to be used with care at first.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Indeed, I've only heard it in “awww” situations — never (so far?!) in the tea situation.